# Navigate to LWR Community Home Page

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, navigationmixin.navigate, lwr

I have pretty simple Custom Modal LWC.
I want it to navigate to Customer Portal Home Page onclose of the modal.
Below is the code:

```
import LightningModal from 'lightning/modal';
import {NavigationMixin} from "lightning/navigation";

export default class DonorRegistrationModal extends NavigationMixin(LightningModal) {
    
    handleOkay() {
        this.close('okay');
        this.navigateToHomePage();
    }

    navigateToHomePage() {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'comm__namedPage',
            attributes: {
                name: 'Home'
            }
        })
    }
}
```

So, when clicking OK button I expect the modal to close and the page to be redirected to Home Page.

Actually I get exception.

**Uncaught (in promise) Error: LWR4002: Could not find context to perform navigation action.**

I cannot find any information regarding this exception.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason is that **NavigationMixin** cannot be applied to **LightningModal**.
Modal can pass parameter via **close()** method to the parent **LWC** which itself can redirect with help of **NavigationMixin**.

Answer (score 0):

The possible reason for this error is that the navigation service requires a context to perform the navigation action, and the context is lost when the modal is closed.

To fix this, you may need to use a different approach to close the modal and navigate to the home page.

For example, you can try using the following steps:

- In your modal component, instead of calling the close method and the navigateToHomePage method in the handleOkay method, emit a custom event with a payload that indicates the action to be performed. For example:

.

```
 handleOkay() {
       const event = new CustomEvent('closemodal', {
         detail: {
           action: 'navigate'
         }
       });
       this.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
```

- In your parent component, handle the custom event and perform the navigation action based on the payload.
- For example:

.

```
handleCloseModal(event) {
   const action = event.detail.action;
   if (action === 'navigate') {
      this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
      type: 'comm__namedPage',
      attributes: {
          name: 'Home'
        }
      });
   }
   this.template.querySelector('c-donor-registration-modal').close();
}
```

This way, you can avoid the error and navigate to the home page on close of the modal.

Comment: Thanks a lot for yor comment. I tried to implement your solution and nothing happened, neither the page was redirected, nor the modal closed. I tryed not to call close() method of Modal but only Navigate, the result is the same exception...